# I have a sentinel while loop with if statments inside them, I want to break out of the if statements without breaking out of the while loop C#

Tags: c#

I am supposed to use only a sentinel while loop for an assignment. The user is meant to enter a department code, and for each department code its supposed to intake a mark and then at the end when the while loop is exited it calculates the average. My question is can I break out an an If statement inside a while loop without breaking out of the while loop itself? And once Q is pressed exit out of the program?

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a department code: ‘C’ or ‘c’ for Computer Science,‘M’ or " +
             "‘m’ for Math, ‘B’ or ‘b’ for Business Admin, or enter ‘Q’ or ‘q’ to quit => C");

            char deptCode = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

            while (char.ToUpper(deptCode) != 'Q')
            {

                if (char.ToUpper(deptCode) == 'C')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the mark (>= 0 or <= 100)");
                    computerScienceMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    break;
                }


                else if (char.ToUpper(deptCode) == 'B')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the mark (>= 0 or <= 100)");
                    businessMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    break;
                }


                else if (char.ToUpper(deptCode) == 'M')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the mark (>= 0 or <= 100)");
                    mathMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    break;
                }

                if (char.ToUpper(deptCode) == 'Q')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you entered Q to quit");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou entered a wrong input please try again");
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: "can I break out an an If statement inside a while loop without breaking out of the while loop" -- What do you mean by that? Maybe augment your code with comments that indicate under which condition to jump from where to where to make your intent clearer.

Comment: Sorry I should have made this more clear but what I meant is that I want the code to ask for one department code (which is asked above the shown code). Then when the user either enters C,B,M it will ask for the user to enter a mark. Once a mark is entered it should ask for a department code again

Comment: Just an unrelated suggestion, please dont put white between if-elseif blocks. The Allman style already provides the right amount of space to clearly identify the different blocks

Comment: @stickybit ok I will take your suggestion and Ill edit the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the whole request for a department code inside a while.
That way the users will be asked for a new code until they enter 'Q', like this

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a department code: ‘C’ or ‘c’ for Computer Science,‘M’ or ‘m’ for Math, ‘B’ or ‘b’ for Business Admin, or enter ‘Q’ or ‘q’ to quit => C");

    char deptCode = Console.ReadLine()[0];
    
    if (char.ToUpper(deptCode) == 'Q')
        break;
    
    if (char.ToUpper(deptCode) == 'C')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the mark (>= 0 or <= 100)");
        computerScienceMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else if (char.ToUpper(deptCode) == 'B')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the mark (>= 0 or <= 100)");
        businessMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else if (char.ToUpper(deptCode) == 'M')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the mark (>= 0 or <= 100)");
        mathMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou entered a wrong input please try again");
    }
}
```

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/8Wi

Answer (score 1):

You want two loops. One outer one to get the department codes, and one inner one to get the mark. Something along the lines of:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true) // outer loop
    {
        string department;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter department code:");
        department = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

        if (department == "Q")
        {
            break; // end the outer loop
        }
        else if (department == "C"
                  || department == "B"
                   || department == "M")
        {
            while (true) // inner loop
            {
                int mark;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter mark:");
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out mark)
                    && mark >= 0
                    && mark <= 100))
                {
                    break; // end the inner loop;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid mark. Try again.");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid department code. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

To end the outer loop check if `department` was `"Q"` and `break`. For the inner one `break` when the `mark` was correctly entered. You can use `int.TryParse()` to check if the string entered really represents an integer for that check.